# How does fetchMore return data to the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to follow the example of cursor-based paginating with React Apollo (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/pagination/#cursor-based) but am struggling with *how my component that rendered the original data gets the new (appended) data*.

This is how we get the original data and pass it to the component:

```
const { data: { comments, cursor }, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery(
    MORE_COMMENTS_QUERY
);

<Comments
      entries={comments || []}
      onLoadMore={...}
/>
```

What I'm unsure of is how the `fetchMore` function works.

```
onLoadMore={() =>
        fetchMore({
          query: MORE_COMMENTS_QUERY,
          variables: { cursor: cursor },
          updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
            const previousEntry = previousResult.entry;
            const newComments = fetchMoreResult.moreComments.comments;
            const newCursor = fetchMoreResult.moreComments.cursor;

            return {
              // By returning `cursor` here, we update the `fetchMore` function
              // to the new cursor.
              cursor: newCursor,
              entry: {
                // Put the new comments in the front of the list
                comments: [...newComments, ...previousEntry.comments]
              },
              __typename: previousEntry.__typename
            };
          }
        })
      }
```

From what I understand, yes, once my component will cal this `onLoadMore` function (using a button's onClick for example), it will fetch the data based on a new cursor.

My question is this. I'm sorry if this is too simple and I'm not understanding something basic.

**How does the component get the new data?**

I know the data is there, because I console logged the `newComments` (in my case, it wasn't newComments, but you get the idea.) And I saw the new data! But those new comments, how are they returned to the component that needs the data? And if I click the button again, it is still stuck on the same cursor as before.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `updateQuery` function lets you modify (override) the result for the current query. At the same time your component is subscribed to the query and will get the new result. Let's play this through:

- Your component is rendered for the first time, component will subscribe to the query and receive the current result of the query from the cache if there is any. If not the query starts fetching from the GraphQL server and your component gets notified about the loading state.
- If the query was fetched your component will get the data once the result came in. It now shows the first x results. In the cache an entry for your query field is created. This might look something like this:

```js
{
  "Query": {
    "cursor": "cursor1",
    "entry": { "comments": [{ ... }, { ... }] }
  }
} 

// normalised
{
  "Query": {
    "cursor": "cursor1",
    "entry": Ref("Entry:1"),
  }
  "Entry:1": {
    comments: [Ref("Comment:1"), Ref("Comment:2")],
  },
  "Comment:1": { ... },
  "Comment:2": { ... }
}
```

- User clicks on load more and your query is fetched again but with the cursor value. The cursor tells the API from which entry it should start returning values. In our example after `Comment` with id `2`.
- Query result comes in and you use the `updateQuery` function to manually update the result of the query in the cache. The idea here is that we want to merge the old result (list) with the new result list. We already fetched 2 comments and now we want to add the two new comments. You have to return a result that is the combined result from two queries. For this we need to update the cursor value (so that we can click "load more" again and also concat the lists of comments. The value is written to the cache and our normalised cache now looks like this:

```js
{
  "Query": {
    "cursor": "cursor2",
    "entry": { "comments": [{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }, { ... }] }
  }
}

// normalised
{
  "Query": {
    "cursor": "cursor2",
    "entry": Ref("Entry:1"),
  }
  "Entry:1": {
    comments: [Ref("Comment:1"), Ref("Comment:2"), Ref("Comment:3"), Ref("Comment:4")],
  },
  "Comment:1": { ... },
  "Comment:2": { ... },
  "Comment:3": { ... },
  "Comment:4": { ... }
}
```

- Since your component is subscribed to the query it will get rerendered with the new query result from the cache! The data is displayed in the UI because we merged the query so that the component gets new data just as if the result had all four comments in the first place.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. I was not returning data in the exact same shape/format as the original data. I had forgotten the `__typename`.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how you handle the offset. I'll try to simplify an example for you.

This is a simplified component that I use successfully:

```
const PlayerStats = () => {
  const { data, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery(CUMULATIVE_STATS, {
    variables: sortVars,
  })

  const players = data.GetCumulativeStats

  const loadMore = () => {
    fetchMore({
      variables: { offset: players.length },
      updateQuery: (prevResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
        if (!fetchMoreResult) return prevResult
        return {
          ...prevResult,
          GetCumulativeStats: [
            ...prevResult.GetCumulativeStats,
            ...fetchMoreResult.GetCumulativeStats,
          ],
        }
      },
    })
  }
```

My `CUMULATIVE_STATS` query returns 50 rows by default. I pass the length of that result array to my `fetchMore` query as `offset`. So when I execute `CUMULATIVE_STATS` with `fetchMore`, the variables of the query are both `sortVars` and `offset`.

My resolver in the backend handles the `offset` so that if it is, for example, 50, it ignores the first 50 results of the query and returns the next 50 from there (ie. rows 51-100).

Then in the `updateQuery` I have two objects available: `prevResult` and `fetchMoreResult`. At this point I just combine them using spread operator. If no new results are returned, I return the previous results.

When I have fetched more once, the results of `players.length` becomes 100 instead of 50. And that is my new offset and new data will be queried the next time I call `fetchMore`.